# Правильная настройка mysql, nginx, php-fpm

Tags: mysql, nginx, php-fpm

Посещаемость сайта в сутки 3000 человек. На сайте есть моменты времени, когда с каждого пользователя(а их около 200 человек онлайном) поступает около 100-150 запросов в минуту, итог, сайт падает с 502 ошибкой nginx. На сервере грузятся все процессы, а занятая память не превышает 1100М.

Конфигурация сервера: Intel Xeon CPU E3-1230 v3 @ 3.30GHz 2400.000 Mhz,
32 GB RAM, 256 SSD, 1 GB канал.

Настрйоки nginx 1.10.1-1:

```
worker_processes 8;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

events {
 worker_connetctions 1024;
 multi_accept on;
 use epoll;
}

sendfile on;
keepalive_timeout 30;
keepalive_requests 1000;
proxy_connect_timeout 604800;
proxy_send_timeout 604800;
proxy_read_timeout 604800;
```

Включено gzip сжатие 5 уровня.

На php-fpm 5.6 увеличил memory_limit на 512M.

Настройка mysql 5.5.55:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql.log
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
local-infile=0

table_open_cache = 3072
table_definition_cache = 4096
max_heap_table_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_connections = 505
max_user_connections = 500
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_cache_size = 32
query_cache_size = 64M

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

[mysqldump]
quick
single-transaction
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no_auto_rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit = 8192
log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

# InnoDB
default_table_type             = InnoDB

# 80% of ram that is dedicated for the database (this needs to be adjusted to your system)
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 24G
# number of CPU cores dedicated to the MySQL InnoDB backend 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16 

innodb_data_file_path          = ibdata1:128M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_log_file_size           = 512M
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2

# MyISAM
myisam_recover                 = backup,force

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Пытался настроить по:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50941/the-best-mysql-settings-for-32gb-ram-on-a-dedicated-server

Статистика htop сервера во время нагрузки:
[image: htop]

Comment: Сжатие достаточно тяжелая для процессора процедура. Вы точно не пытаетесь выполнять сжатие на динамических данных?

Comment: Я не особо уверен, что сжатие там играет роль, тк все эти 200 запросов поступают через websocket. Те пользователи не получают контент 150-200 раз в минуту, а просто отправляют запросы через сокеты.

Comment: Да и памяти всего используется 1100M, при свободных 32G.

Comment: извиняюсь, невнимательно читал вопрос. Основную нагрузку  создает mysql?

Comment: Получается, на nginx, базовые параметры я установил, и уж 200 пользователей онлайн он должен выдержать. Вся нагрузка идет на mysql + php-fpm, верно, предполагаю, что mysql настроен не верно, и не использует все возможности сервера.

Comment: Тогда вопрос к организации БД - какие индексы и какие SQL-запросы. Если, например, каждый запрос модифицирует сложный индекс из многих полей, то это может тормознуть. Ну и наоборот, если данные извлекаются без хорошего индекса, то это приведет к filesort, тоже может тормознуть. Однако, у вас и процессы php-fpm нормально так нагружают процессор.

Comment: Предполагаю, что лучшим решением будет для начала настроить cfg, для использования всего сервера, а потом уже лезть в индексы и саму структуру базы) Собственно я и привел конфиг файлы, для того, что бы мне показали на ошибки в них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL использует подозрительно мало памяти. Скорее всего, огромный запрос на innodb_buffer_size = 24G, да еще умноженный на 16 innodb_buffer_pool_instances, просто игнорируется MySQL. Вы запрашиваете ни много ни мало 384G памяти под innodb. Где их взять? У вас совокупный объем памяти 32 + 1 GB. Скорее всего, в логе mysql есть ошибки, проверьте.

Число innodb_buffer_pool_instances ставят обычно по числу процессоров, а общий объём не должен превышать 80% памяти. Да, эту дурацкую рекомендацию я читал не раз. В ней всего одна ошибка - у вас ВСЕ в системе должно влезать в 80% памяти - mysql, php-fpm, nginx.

Для mysql есть [неплохой калькулятор](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/) (только они забыли про innodb_buffer_pool_instances).

Так что в вашем случае я бы поставил

```
innodb_buffer_size = 2.4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
```

Дальше. В mysql есть совершенно непонятная мне проблема - по умолчанию запросы не кэшируются: query_cache_type = OFF.

Добавление примерно таких настроек у меня на сервере **радикально** изменило скорость доступа к базе.

```
query_cache_type = ON
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 2M
```

php вы зря увеличили memory limit - он столько не просит, судя по htop. Оставьте 128M по умолчанию в php7. А, да - так у вас php 5.6! Сносите его и ставьте php7. Семерка почти вдвое быстрее, а судя по htop, у вас php сидит на процессоре.

И постарайтесь кэшировать все, что возможно в вашем приложении. Более подробные советы по настройке сервера на высокую производительность можно посмотреть в моей статье "[10,000 соединений в секунду на WordPress](https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/)".

Comment: Точку забыл: 2.4G на один буфер, а не 24

Comment: Спасибо, поправлю cfg по вашим рекомендациям. По поводу innodb_buffer_pool_instances, согласен, очень странно учитывается данная настройка.  Что насчет php, пока установил pm = dynamic, pm.max_children = 200, pm.start_servers = 100, pm.min_spare_servers = 50, pm.max_spare_servers = 100, pm.max_requests = 500. Посмотрим, как изменится нагрузка

Comment: Не понял насчет php

Comment: Конфигурация процессов http://logvik.com/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-nginxphp-fpm/php-fpm

Comment: Коммент ваш обрезанный был сначала, я потому и не понял. Настройки вы слишком большие поставили, на мой взгляд. У вас php процессы сожрут почти всю память. А куда mysql? Куда nginx девать?

Comment: В любом случае проверю эти настройки, на живом проекте, возможность позволяет. Я прочитал вашу статью, по wordpress, расписано все от и до, спасибо, в ночь переконфигурируем все, когда активность упадет.

Comment: А лучше перенесу все на второй сервер digitalocean, настрою по статье и проведу тесты, заодно перенесу на php7.

Comment: Вот это правильно

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скриншотам, у вас падает сервер из-за нагрузки MySQL. Дело не в серверных настройках (здесь все относительно нормально), а в архитектуре вашего web-приложения. А учитывая, что у вас достаточно хорошая тачка "Intel Xeon CPU E3-1230 v3 @ 3.30GHz 2400.000 Mhz, 32 GB RAM, 256 SSD, 1 GB канал.", то можно однозначно сказать, что ее рушит неправильно спроектированное приложение.

Вот несколько советов:

**Индексы**

Важно! Думаю это и есть причина ваших падений.

Очень подозреваю, что учитывая ваше достаточно хорошее железо и небольшую нагрузку на сайт у вас не выставлены или неправильно выставлены в таблицах индексы. При правильной настройке индексов (под профиль нагрузки) MySQL отлично справляется гораздо более высокими нагрузками и на более слабом железе.

**Оптимизация запросов**

Посмотрите через профайлер (например, XDebug) какие запросы выполняются наиболее долго и проведите их оптимизацию.

Если INSERT/UPDATE-запросы в коде идут подряд, то отправляйте их на сервер пачкой, а не по одному. Также используйте транзакции.

Сократите общее количество запросов к базе. Где можно обойтись одним запросом, не делайте их несколько. Особенно обратите внимание на запросы, которые делаются в циклах (например, часто встречается в лентах новостей, личных сообщениях и других блоках, где есть агрегация данных). Это надо исключить. Запрашивайте данные одним запросом (например, в первом запросе определяете id, по которым надо сделать второй запрос с данными id, а далее выполняете сопоставление данных - подставляете недостающие для первого запроса данные полученными из второго).

**Memcached**

Установите для повторяющихся (SELECT) и редко меняющихся (UPDATE) запросов сервер Memcached. Выделите 3-4Gb на кэширование запросов.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Перенесем сессии в memcached, из базы. Насчет индексов, будем проверять. Не совсем уверен, что дело в них.Когда писал пост, рассчитывал, что кто-нибудь укажет на неправильную конфигурацию в mysql, отметит важные переменные. По статистике видно, что основная нагрузка на mysql и php-fpm процессы. С php-fpm уже разобрался, не были настроены процессы. Посмотрим, что из этого получится.

Comment: @azimut да, в сессиях может быть все дело (если вы храните их в базе). особенно в эту таблицу делайте запросы только по первичному ключу! например, если вы выставляете куки с токеном, то используйте session_id, чтобы найти в базе эту сессию и только потом проверяйте token.

Comment: @azimut с переносом сессий в memcached надо быть аккуратнее. смотрите, чтобы кэш правильно обновлялся при закрытии и открытии сессий, а то (пользователь введя логин и пароль еще несколько десятков секунд будет недоумевать почему он не зашел на сайт)))

Comment: в любом случае, куча памяти проставивает просто так, и ее нужно использовать, а значит cfg настроены не под сервер.

Comment: @azimut ну это уже дело десятое) а если хотите устранить причину падений, то она весьма вероятно заключена в той таблице, где вы храните сессии (скорее всего неправильно настроены индексы или их вообще нет).

Comment: Собственно вот так хранятся сессии: https://packagist.org/packages/nitecon/zf2-db-session

Comment: @azimut, это еще может значить, что используемые программы перегружают процессор, а не память.

Comment: И да) вы правы, никаких индексов в данной таблице нет, а все крутится вокруг нее.

Comment: @azimut да, уже глянул, там только первичный индекс по id выставлен, но важно понимать как идет SELECT запрос на выборку данных. подозреваю, что там еще идет поиск по полю name (которое к тому же varchar) или data (которое вообще text).

Comment: Поиск идет только по полю id, после того, как запись найдена, данные выбираются из data и уже идет работа с ними. Вот и вся логика.

Comment: @azimut хм, тогда надо смотреть через профайлер профиль нагрузки, чтобы точно определить тормозящие базу запросы.

Comment: @azimut используйте xdebug, а для вывода полученных данных webgrind. там смотрите обращения к базе. что и сколько идет по времени.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Такой момент, а разве PRIMARY_KEY не устанавливает сразу индекс на поле id?

Comment: @azimut да, это индекс по умолчанию. более того, выборки по PRIMARY KEY более быстрые.

Comment: Тогда получается в таблице сессий все впорядке с индексацией.

Comment: в любом случае, надо смотреть профайлер, там уже определенно будет видно где нагрузка.